# HTML Div Alignment Issue (Without Fixed Width)

Tags: html, css

I have a an HTML as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/9sWbc/1/. I need to  make the Address in one line and other three columns  (City State and Country) in second line. The width of each column should not be fixed. How can we achieve it?

Comment: Thanks to all answers. Removing the width 100% helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this is what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/9sWbc/6/

EDITED CSS:

```
#infoDiv
{
     width:550px;
     border:1px solid Red;
}
.dataLine
{    
    width:100%;
    min-width:650px;
    height:auto;
    margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    /*border:1px solid Cyan;*/
}
.freeTwoColumnFirstEntry
{    
    height:auto;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    padding:0 0 0 2px;
    font:normal 9pt Arial;
    display:inline;

}
.freeTwoColumnSecondEntry
{    
    height:auto;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    padding:0 0 0 2px;
    font:normal 9pt Arial;
    display:inline;

}
#cityDiv, #cityDivVal, #stateDiv, #stateDivVal, #countryDiv, #countryDivVal{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: have edited this a little bit..instead of inline, the div's should actually be inline-block (to enable margin-left, margin-right properties to this div as well)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/9sWbc/7/
Check this jsfiddle link, It is displaying address in first line, abd  city state county in second line.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will make the Address in one line and other three columns (City State and Country) in second line.

```
<div id="wrapper1">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="header1">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div id="centralContainer1">
            <div id="mainContainer1">
                <div id="contentHolderDiv1" class="contentHolderDiv1">
                    <div id="searchContainer" class="searchContainer">
                        <div id="entryValues" class="searchValuesDiv">
                            <div id="infoDiv">

                                <div id="address1Div" class="dataLine">
                                    <span class="freeTwoColumnFirstEntry">
                                        Address:
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="freeTwoColumnSecondEntry">
                                        <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_lblAddress1">Santhom Avenue, 3456</span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div id="cityStateCountryDiv" class="dataLine">
                                    <span id="cityDiv" class="freeTwoColumnFirstEntry">
                                        City:
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="cityDivVal" class="freeTwoColumnSecondEntry">
                                        <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_lblCity">Akron</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="stateDiv" class="freeTwoColumnFirstEntry">
                                        State:
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="stateDivVal" class="freeTwoColumnSecondEntry">
                                        <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_lblState">OH</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="countryDiv" class="freeTwoColumnFirstEntry">
                                        Country:
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="countryDivVal" class="freeTwoColumnSecondEntry">
                                        <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_lblCountry">United States</span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```